# Python plot sub plots with x as Index

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to do a plot that uses sub plots in Python, but it doesn't seem to be working.
SO I have a dataframe and there is an Index. This index holds datetime. I have two columns that I would like to plot, and I am trying to use sub plots. Data1 and Data2 are my column names. My code is below

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(x=df[index], y=df['Data1'])
ax2.plot(x=df[index], y=df['Data2'])

plt.show()
```

When I run this I get the following error.

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Print out the contents of `df[index]`, and `df['Data1']`.  They're not the integers that the plot method is expecting.

Comment: So the index is a datetime type and Data1 and Data2 are float64

Comment: `df[index]` doesn't make sense in the code you provided because `index` is never defined. maybe you mean `df.index` which is completely different

Comment: So I had tried using df.index but I get the error       " plot got an unexpected keyword argument 'x' "

Comment: just remove the `x=` and `y=`, i.e. `ax1.plot(df.index, df['Data1'])` and `ax2.plot(df.index, df['Data2'])`